# Google Kubernetes Engine not dynamically provisioning volumes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to get a Persisten Volume Claim on GKE and to my understanding using either the `standard` storage class or the proposed `fast` storage class I should get a disk provisioned, however I've been waiting for 30 minutes and no disk is being provisioned
[image]

my storage classes are the ones in the documentation
[image]

More over, I tried both approaches

with the `faster` class

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim2
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: faster
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

and `standard`

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim-slow
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

It's been so long that I don't think the volumes are getting provisioned automatically, what could I be missing?

Comment: I do not think that Google Kubernetes supports `ReadWriteMany`. Only `ReadWriteOnce` and `ReadOnlyMany`.  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the “accessModes” to any of these [Access Modes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#access_modes) but not “ReadWriteMany”. GCE persistent disk does not support “ReadWriteMany” access mode. 
You can also run the command:

```
Kubectl describe [Persistent Volume Claim NAME]
```

This will show you why it is failing to create.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I see the error `Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "faster": invalid AccessModes [ReadWriteMany]: only AccessModes [ReadWriteOnce ReadOnlyMany] are supported` so I changed to `ReadWriteOnce`

Comment: on the link it says it supports "ReadWriteMany" and still doesnt work